# Cannot get Laravel Mail::to()->later() to work

Tags: laravel, redis

I'm trying to send a time-delayed email via a Redis queue and Mailgun using the following code...

```
$when = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5);
Mail::to($demoDownloader->Email)->later($when, new DemoRequestFollowUp($demoDownloader));
```

I can see that the job is added to the redis queue (using Redis Desktop Manager) and stays in the queue for 5 minutes before disappearing from the queue. Unfortunately, it never appears in the Mailgun logs.

If I instead use this line of code...

```
Mail::to($demoDownloader->Email)->send(new DemoRequestFollowUp($demoDownloader));
```

...then the email appears in the Mailgun logs and subsequently arrives in the destination mailbox successfully (minus the time delay of course).

No error messages are written to storage/logs/laravel.log so I'm at a bit of a loss as to why this isn't working. I'm pretty sure I've used the syntax specified in the manual.

By the way, my mailable looks like this...

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use \App\DemoDownloader;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class DemoRequestFollowUp extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $requestee;

    public function __construct(DemoDownloader $requestee)
    {
        $this->requestee = $requestee;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Overview')
                    ->view('email-demo-request-follow-up');
    }
}
```

I'd be most grateful for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd neglected to look in the `failed_jobs` table which gave me the clue I needed...

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException: No query results for model [App\DemoDownloader]
```

As the `DemoDownloader` instance being passed into the `DemoRequestFollowUp` constructor wasn't actually being used, I removed the argument and also removed the `$requestee` public property from the class and its assignment in the constructor. After making these changes emails were reliably arriving after the specified delay interval had passed.